# get request failing in boto3 python 3.8 lambda

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying to write a lambda function in 3.8 version but I am getting error while doing a get requests

```
[ERROR] AttributeError: module 'botocore.vendored.requests' has no attribute 'get' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/lambda_function.py"

import json
from botocore.vendored import requests

def lambda_handler(event, context):

    request = event['Records'][0]['cf']['request']
    print (request)
    print(request['headers'])
    token = request['headers']['cookie'][0]['value'].partition("=")[2]
    print (token)
    print(type(request['uri']))
    consumer_id = request['uri'].rpartition('/')[-1]
    print (consumer_id)

    #Take the token and send it somewhere
    token_response = requests.get(url = 'https://url/api/files/'  + consumer_id, params = {'token': token})
    print (token_response)

    return request
```

I tried following this blog https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/upcoming-changes-to-the-python-sdk-in-aws-lambda/

but not able to identify which layer to add. Could anyone please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the link you provided and assuming that `request` was correctly installed you should be using

```
import requests
```

instead of

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
```

Comment: shall I create the bundle first? and then the package ? which arn of the layer shall I use? my lambda function is in virginia region

Comment: @cloudbud for n.virgina: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:668099181075:layer:AWSLambda-Python-AWS-SDK:4

Comment: now when I try to deploy lambda@egde I get Correct the errors above and try again.
Layers aren't supported.

Comment: @cloudbud If you use lambda@edge then you have to bundle the requests in your deployment zip package.

Comment: how can I do that?

Comment: @cloudbud the link you posted explains how to do it.

Comment: @cloudbud Any luck ?

Comment: yes I was able to bundle it without layers. using this article that you posted https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/build-python-lambda-deployment-package/ I just installed the request module making the bundle light

Comment: @cloudbud Glad to hear and thank you. If my help was useful, I would appreciate accepting my answers to your two questions regarding the `requests` issues.

Comment: can you help me with my new question

Answer (score 0):

You want to create a layer with a requests installed onto zip file before hand and then use import requests

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution on Python runtime 3.9, so this isn't guaranteed to work for any other versions. I do not claim that this is the *best* solution, but it worked for me and may point others towards a better solution as the currently available answers do not solve the problem.

1. **Create a local directory** for your Lambda function code and dependencies.
2. **Create your Lambda function code** in a file in your new local directory you made in step #1. Name it `lambda_function.py`:

   ```py
   import requests
   from datetime import datetime

   def lambda_handler(event, context):
       # Your code goes here
       print(datetime.now())
       response = requests.get('https://api.example.com')
       return response.text
   ```
3. **Install the `requests` library** in your project directory. This is important for Python runtime in AWS Lambda:

   ```bash
   pip install requests -t ./
   ```
4. **Compress your local directory** into a ZIP file.
5. **Upload your ZIP file** to the AWS Lambda function. Ensure your project contents are in the root of the default folder.